# How do i get a integer value of a 32bit IEEE value in python

Tags: python, ieee

How do i get a integer value of a 32bit IEEE value in python
for example 01000000010000000000000000000000 would give me the integer 3.
How do i do this?

I would 0 100000001 0000000000000000000000 is respectively signbit, expononent and then fraction values.

Im just wondering how would I code something like this in python.
What are the steps or if anyone can help me with code to learn from that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear to me how are you getting this IEEE value?  Do you have a string that is 32 _bytes_ long (all `'1'` and `'0'`) or 32 _bits_ long?

Comment: hi, it's has 32 0's and 1's.

Comment: The best guess I could provide would be to look into struct.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty round-about way of doing it... First interpret the string as an integer (base 2):

```
>>> s = '01000000010000000000000000000000'
>>> i = int(s, 2)
>>> i
1077936128
```

Now you can get the integer bitwise representation of that integer using `struct.pack`:

```
>>> b = struct.pack('i', i)
>>> b
'\x00\x00@@'
```

And finally, you can `struct.unpack` those bytes as if they were a float:

```
>>> f, = struct.unpack('f', b)
>>> f
3.0
```

Comment: @kpie -- This is one of those times where I was hesitant to answer... I feel like there's gotta be a better way to do it.

Comment: Na dude literally I rushed to post int(bytes(...)) before I realized what the question was really asking.

Comment: But is the ,= supposed to be there?

Comment: @kpie Yes, it's a tuple assignment.  `struct.unpack` returns a one-element list I believe.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a roundabout way, it's pretty much exactly how you would do this in C.